# How to working Owasp ZAP on web interface

Tags: owasp, zap

I do not want to use it from the desktop application. I need software that works on the web.

I want to use it on a server. Personnel who want to use ZAP need to do this by connecting to that server.

I could only run the desktop application

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have a plan for this, otherwise known as ZAP as a Service (ZaaS). Its not progressing as quickly as we'd like, due to lack of contributors. If you (or anyone else) has suitable skills and would like to work on ZAP then we'd be very pleased to hear from you :)

Simon (ZAP project lead)

Answer (score 1):

One possible option, is to run the official container with webswing according to the official wiki: https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/docker/webswing/

TLDR; Stable:

1. `docker run -d --name zaproxy -u zap -p 8080:8080 -p 8090:8090 -i owasp/zap2docker-stable zap-webswing.sh`
2. visit http://localhost:8080 (http! *not* https!)

> Starting with version 2.5.0 you can run the ZAP Desktop UI in your
> browser without having to install Java, thanks to the magic of Docker
> and Webswing
>
> To do this you will just need Docker installed. Start the container
> with webswing support:
>
> Stable: docker run -u zap -p 8080:8080 -p 8090:8090 -i
> owasp/zap2docker-stable zap-webswing.sh
>
> Weekly: docker run -u zap -p
> 8080:8080 -p 8090:8090 -i owasp/zap2docker-weekly zap-webswing.sh Then
> point your browser at:
>
> http://localhost:8080/zap You will then see the familiar ZAP splash
> screen while ZAP starts up.

Answer (score 0):

One of the options you could follow is setting up a VNC Server ( https://archive.realvnc.com/products/vnc/documentation/4.6/unix/man/Xvnc.html) on the target and grant user/SSH access to N desktops for your users so that each could spawn it's own proxy - providing they don't port collide. There's a security recommendation to provide VNC access through an SSH tunnel, so you need to keep that in mind. Also would recommend to disable 'password' SSH access and work with users with properly protected SSH identities aka keys.

Answer (score 0):

While waiting for a native Web GUI you can do as the ZAP team did with ZAP on docker using Webswing.

Webswing allows you to use a Java Swing application through the browser, so the result will be the ZAP GUI through your browser.

First you'll have to install Webswing and ZAP and if you're using a headless linux server you'll have to install xvfb.

Second you'll have to create a Webswing configuration file for running ZAP through Webswing. You can use the [configuration file](https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/blob/develop/docker/webswing.config) used by the ZAP docker or you can create one using the [tutorial](https://www.webswing.org/docs/20.1/start/quickstart.html#setup-your-own-application) provided by Webswing

Finally, enjoy!